# Is Caja stripping the #= out of my URLs to spreadsheets?

Tags: google-apps-script

In an AppsScript web application, after someone has submitted a form, I would like to return a page that says thank you and includes a link back to particular sheet in a spreadsheet.

I am passing the sheet id as template variable like this...

```
    <a href="<?!= spreadsheet_url ?>#gid<?!= '=' ?><?!= sheet_id ?>" ><?= link_text?></a>
```

... but what I'm finding is that the equals AFTER the hash is rendered as percent-3-d ( %3d ).

Is this Caja getting in the way or something else? I don't seem to be able to meddle with a link's URL ( although an equals sign happily can be added to the query args ).

Thanks

Tom

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Caja blocks such elementary harmless stuff. In any case, you can verify it at the [Caja playground](http://caja.appspot.com/). 
The %3d you are seeing is because of URL encoding. URL encoding is quite common and you can read more about it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).